# How do I recreate a grappling hook swing effect using Bukkit/Spigot API?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm working on a minecraft plugin project that needs a grappling hook with a swing mechanism kind of like in karlson (https://streamable.com/uud2fe - example of what mechanism i mean),

after messing around i got to this line of code which just boosts the player towards the block that is getting hit (I'm using a projectilehitevent)

```
    p.setVelocity(event.getHitBlock().getLocation().toVector().subtract(p.getLocation().toVector()).normalize().multiply(0.45f));`
 //  (p refers to the player)
```

I don't have much experience with vectors so help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: I am looking into it. I have some code done but it doesn't work exactly as I would want. I will post it when I solve some bugs with an extensive explanation of what it does.

Comment: @PauMAVA that's good to hear! thanks for taking this on you, looking to see it